# Apprequest DialogListener's return bundle array type

Tags: android, facebook, bundle, apprequests

Hello everybody i'm trying to get the returned values from an apprequest invite so i did this;

```
public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
final int[] to = values.getIntArray("to");
int n = to.length
}
```

But when i use the n variable this is the LogCat:

```
08-26 18:40:04.312: E/AndroidRuntime(6464): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have tryed with getIntArray, getFloatArray, getLongArray, getStringArray but nothing works. If i look the page of Facebook Developer it says this:

```
An array of the recipient user IDs for the request that was created.
```

But it doesn't say what is the array type. Thank You

Comment: you could use values.keySet() to check whether the key is present.

Comment: the key is present because if i do values.toString(); it return Bundle[{to[0]=1717519348, request=510342092684268}]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for nandeesh's hint, I found it's strange that we cannot retrieve the data in array type.

Every recipient user's ID should be retrieved with different keys.

I tried the following code and it works now.

```
Set<String> keys = values.keySet();
int userNum = values.keySet().size() - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < userNum; i++) {
    Log.d("user IDs", values.getString("to[" + String.format("%1$d", i) + "]"));
}
```

Comment: values.keySet(); is a set<String>. how i can do -1 if is a string and not a number ?

Comment: Sorry, it should be values.keySet().size() - 1.
I've corrected the answer above.

Comment: Thank You Very Much. Please edit your answer for future user :)